# Looping through json object returned from jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have returned three values from an ajax call. Here is the content of the json object in my console log:

```
{"no":"img2","name":"mylogo.jpg","location":"u_images\/1\/"}
```

-No is meant to refer to the thumbnail div container where i want to display a thumbnail of the image uploaded by the user

-name is obviously the name of the file

-location refers to the file path where the user has uploaded the file to, where i want to grab the file and display in the thumbnail.

-1 at the end of the location is the folder which is given the id of the user.

Here is what i've tried:

```
   success: function(data)
    {

       if (data != '') 
       { 
            //console.log(data);

            var data = $.parseJSON(data);

            $(data).each(function(num,name,loc) //this looks stupid i know,but it's just the last   //of the hundred things i've tried-i know the fault has to lie here in my loop syntax.

       {
            var imgsrc = loc+'name'; 
            $('#'+num+'div').html('<img src="'+imgsrc+'" width="50" height="50" />');

       });

     }
 }
```

So when i submit the form, i get the returned object in my console log alright, but my other code to replace the loading gif image in the thumbnail with the image of the file just uploaded does not work, and i get no errors either.

Any help or advice much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you need a loop? `data.no`, `data.name` and `data.location` have what you want.

Comment: And you probably already have an object in there. There should be no need to json.parse it.

Comment: @abhitalks And by "JSON" you mean "object".

Comment: Call it json or object it means the same thing, and as you can see i have an object in the result. I have all the values i need, i know. I'm not adept at javascript to get the values out of the object to use.  But my main difficulty is getting the image to display in a div. The div id is 'img2' (will change every time depending on what thumbnail div is clicked), and u have there the location where i want to grab the file from. I could do it in php as these same details are available in a session, but i wanna use javascript. So the code to display the img is what i need. Hope i'm clear enough:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi just in case anyone stumbles on gthis, i just want to close it up as i got it to work thanks to lolka_bolka's lead. All i had to do was this:

```
  success: function(data)
  {     
    if (data != '')
    { 
     data = $.parseJSON(data);
     $(data).each(function(idx, obj) 
         {
            console.log(obj); //Check this
            var imgsrc = obj.location + obj.name;
            $('#' + obj.no + 'div').html('<img src="' + imgsrc + '" width="50" height="50" />');
        });                 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The each function has 2 parameters, the key and the object. Check my code.

```
    var data = '{"no":"img2","name":"mylogo.jpg","location":"u_images\/1\/"} ';
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    $(data).each(function(idx, obj) {
        //console.log(obj); //Check this
        var imgsrc = obj.location + 'name';
        $('#' + idx + 'div').html('<img src="' + imgsrc + '" width="50" height="50" />');

    });
```

Comment: i just tried your code, it didn't work. I got this error in the console:  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: you were very close. You probably just mistyped in a hurry. It made me learn a new way of manipulating the object, so i have it working, it's a shame i can't vote you up-:( don't have a high enough reputation. Thanks alot